# "Functors" which map objects to morphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors, higher-category-theory

I'm just beginning to learn category theory, and this question popped up in my mind, which Googling has not been able to resolve (probably because I am not searching the right terms).

A functor between categories $C,C'$ is a map $T$ that associates each object $c\in C$ with an object $Tc\in C'$, and each morphism $\varphi$ in $C$ with a morphism $T\varphi$ in $C'$, satisfying certain niceness properties (takes identity morphism to the identity, etc.)

> What about a map $T$ from $C$ to $C'$ that takes objects in $C$ to morphisms in $C'$, and morphisms in $C$ to "morphisms between morphisms" in $C'$ instead, satisfying similar "niceness" properties? Do these have a name?

This is in some sense like a "meta" version of functors, and I imagine they have been studied before. I imagine that [higher category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_category_theory) might be relevant, but I unfortunately do not quite understand the Wikipedia page well enough to determine whether or not it's related.

Unless, perhaps, these maps are not well-defined, or not interesting? If so, I am very intrigued to find out why. Indeed my question above is rather vague as I do not really know how to make the notion of transformations between morphisms rigorous. (Maybe it is captured by the notion of a natural transformations? Or, maybe not.)

Any explanations or directions on where to find out more, or the right terms to search, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but your construction make no sense. A map that sends objects in $C$ to morphisms in $C'$ should send morphisms in $C$ to something that goes from one morphism in $C'$ to another, but a natural transformation goes from a functor to another.

Comment: @jiagmath Yup, I realised the same thing just before I saw your comment! See the edited question, thanks :)

Comment: A similar thing does exists. Categories where the objects are functors and the morphisms are natural transformations. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_category

Comment: @jiagmath Thanks for the reference! I will try to understand this notion.

Comment: As en example, consider the Yoneda embedding of a category into its set valued functors, which sends an object $X$ to the the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-, X)$. Describing how this is a functor is a worthwhile exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any category $D$ there is its category of arrows $Arr(D)$. Its objects are the morphisms in $D$, and its morphisms are commuting squares of morphisms in $D$. A functor $C\to Arr(D)$ thus takes the objects of $C$ to morphisms in $D$, and morphisms in $C$ to morphisms between morphisms (at least in a sense). This does not require any higher dimensional considerations.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for; I'd accept this answer soon if no others come along.

Comment: And, by the way, these are just the *natural transformations*.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can map object to a functor such as the famous [Yoneda lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) in CT.

> If $\mathcal {C}$  is a locally small category (i.e. the hom-sets are actual sets and not proper classes), then each object $A$ of $\mathcal {C}$  gives rise to a natural functor to $\mathbf {Set}$ called a hom-functor.

> The original category $\mathcal {C}$  is contained in this functor category, but new objects appear in the functor category, which were absent and "hidden" in $\mathcal {C}$... The Yoneda embedding essentially states that for every (locally small) category, objects in that category can be represented by presheaves, in a full and faithful manner.

But it's impossible to have a well formed map $T$ from $C$ to $C'$ that takes objects in $C$ to morphisms in $C'$ in general. Since usually there may be multiple or infinite morphisms in $C'$ related with any target object in $C'$ from a source object in $C$, then how you can define such a map from a source object to so many target morphisms? You miss the necessary link between your conceived source and target. In contrast, Yoneda lemma mapping a source object to a *functor* preserves this link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "Since usually there may be multiple or infinite morphisms in C′ related with any target object in C′ from a source object in C, then how you can define such a map from a source object to so many target morphisms?" Could you elaborate on this? Sure, there are many choices of morphisms in C' that we could send any object of C to, so there are many choices of the map $T$, but why is this an issue (since we are not requiring that $T$ is unique)? Am I misinterpreting what you mean?

Comment: @YiFan first you need axiom of choice to ensure you can choose such a morphism... Also whole idea of CT is structure preserving under mappings, if you map arbitrarily, what's the use of it can be?

Comment: @mahottnad Yeah, of course it should be structure-preserving, hence the "niceness properties" in the OP. I get your point that there doesn't seem to be a way to choose the target morphism in a sensible way in general, what I meant was that the availability of different choices doesn't make it impossible a priori. Am I interpreting you correctly?

Comment: @YiFan yes you're interpreting me correctly, in general hardly useful...

Comment: I disagree that this is hardly useful. The category of arrows of a category allows one to map functorially from any category to the category of arrows of any other category. Arrow categories, and over and under categories, are very useful. They can be used to speak conveniently of adjunctions and universal properties, they form important fibrations, they appear in categorical logic...

Comment: @IttayWeiss thx for your comment. OP is not asking about category construction involving morphisms , OP only asks about if we can define a "meta" version of functor mapping from objects in category C to morphisms in another arbitrary category C′ (and morphisms in C to "morphisms between morphisms" in C′). I don't see in general it's useful to map an object A in category C to an morphism in an arbitrary category C' which may have nothing to do with object A in C. Of course your arrow, over, under categories are *specific* categories already, and in this case this functorial map may be useful...

Comment: @mohottnad a functor from C to the arrow category of C’ is a precise interpretation of “mapping objects of C to arrows of C’ and morphisms to…” The specific arrow category is used simply in order to re-use the functor concept. But the arrow construction can be applied to *any* category, so it is not a specification.

Comment: @IttayWeiss thx for your clarification. So in what concrete example categories $C$ and $C'$, such a constructed functorial map can shed new light on category $C$ via category $Arr(C')$?

Comment: @mohottnad I'm not entirely sure what sort of example you are after. Perhaps it would be suitable for you to think about that and phrase it as a question rather than in the comments thread.